# Android WebView and Paypal

Tags: java, android, paypal, webview

I'm attempting to open a paypal button in a webview - and until yesterday it worked, but now it just keep loading - similar to screen below but with padlock in to center.
[image]

This is the code I use..

```
private WebView mWebview ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab3);


        mWebview = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview.loadUrl(MainActivity.paypalURL);
        setContentView(mWebview);
    }
```

Comment: what is your URL ?

Comment: Must have something to do with it as others pages seem ok
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=9HQUAVH5932V2

Comment: The link works fine in chrome on android

Comment: Have you consider to use `PayPal Mobile Payment Libraries` - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Comment: Used Iframe in html and uploaded to server and seemed to work well.

Comment: @mark i need your help i need webview URL for paypal integration in flutter app. Please let me know exactly which URL should i use in app ?